# How to load validation data set

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

How do I save the trained and tested Model ? Load the model to validate new dataset i.e.Validation_dataset

Comment: Hi, this question is far too broad for anyone to help! If you have a specific programming problem then please edit the question to include a minimally reproducible example, along with necessary example data and errors. Feel free to ask a question over at Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com) if you are looking for specific guidance on machine learning. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Pleas show us what you've done.